# throw an exception only in debug mode in java

Tags: java, debugging, exception

I want to avoid crashes in the release even if something is wrong. That's why I do not want to throw  exceptions that, I know, are not going to be handled.
In Debug mode I want to do it because it's good to get as much noise as possible when something is wrong during debug.

The problem is that if I do something like:

if (DEBUG_MODE) throw e;

then I need to specify that the method throws an exception but I do not want to do it becasue that is not true in the release.

What's the best way of dealing with this?

**EDIT**

PS

My question was not clear sorry.

In my case assertion are not really convenient. The problem is that I already know that something is wrong so I do not have anything to assert. To make it clearer I have unexpected exceptions. Of course you can say: write the code not to have unexpected exceptions. But in case something is wrong I do not want the application to crash. Now I added a function like this:

```
public static void unexpectedException(String string, Exception e) {
    if (Build.DEBUG) {
        MyApp.errorLog(string);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } else
        MyApp.errorLog(string, e);
}
```

Althought all your answers were correct I'll choose that one that is nearer to what I did

PS2

Another case when the assertion is not really convenient is when you implement a pattern like state. If for some state you expect a method not to ever be called...

Comment: The best way is to always handle exceptions.

Comment: Always use Exceptions for public methods/constructors - document and handle them thoroughly - and assertions for private methods. You have to signal the client if he is doing something wrong with your application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not want to use assertions, as you really should, you can derive your exceptions from `RuntimeException`. Then you do not have to declare them as `throws` in your method header.

That being said, you should really take a look at assertions, or as other replies has said, a proper logging framework.

Answer (score 5):

You can use assertions.

```
public void methodSomething(Object o){

   assert (o != null);  // will throw AssertionError during development

   ...

}
```

But you really should catch those exceptions and handle them (:

Answer (score 5):

Don't **EVER** do that!
Exception should be consistently handled in you application. Use a Logging mechanism to track how your system behave, not by having exception being raised up to the application interface layer.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest [strategy](/questions/tagged/strategy) pattern together with some [dependency-injection](/questions/tagged/dependency-injection) mechanism. Basically create some sort of [`ErrorHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ErrorHandler.html):

```
public interface ErrorHandler {
    void handleError(Throwable t);
}
```

and provide few implementations: <del>`NoOpErrorHandler`,</del> `RethrowingErrorHandler` and `LoggingErrorHandler`. Depending on the environemnt use the one that suits you the most.

However please **at least** log the exceptions!

Answer (score 0):

You can log exceptions like this

```
if(LOGGER.isDebugEnabled())
    LOGGER.log(Level.DEBUG, "What went wrong", e);
```

This allows you to turn on these messages in dev and turn them off in production.